# Filter out properties using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
const ACCEPTABLE_ITEMS = {
    APPLE: true,
    ORANGE: true,
    MANGO: true
};
```

`myItems` might look like this:

```
{
  apple: true,
  orange: true,
  mango: true,
  grapes: true,
  carrots: true
}
```

I want to filter out myItems so that it only includes the properties mentioned in `ACCEPTABLE_ITEMS`. How can I do this with lodash?

I tried doing something like this, but it's not right I think:

```
myItems = _.filter(myItems, (i) => {return ACCEPTABLE_ITEMS[i];});
```

Comment: [`_.pick()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#pick) maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pickBy`:

Working Snippet:P

```js
var ACCEPTABLE_ITEMS = {
  APPLE: true,
  ORANGE: true,
  MANGO: true
};

var myItems = {
  APPLE: true,
  ORANGE: true,
  MANGO: true,
  GRAPES: true,
  CARROTS: true
}

myItems = _.pickBy(myItems, function(i, key) {
  return ACCEPTABLE_ITEMS[key];
});
console.log(myItems);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Update:

To make the condition case insensitive (partially)

```js
var ACCEPTABLE_ITEMS = {
  APPLE: true,
  ORANGE: true,
  MANGO: true
};

var myItems = {
  apple: true,
  ORANGE: true,
  mango: true,
  GRAPES: true,
  CARROTS: true
}

myItems = _.pickBy(myItems, function(i, key) {
  return ACCEPTABLE_ITEMS[key.toUpperCase()];
});
console.log(myItems);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I made a small change to my question. Essentially, myItems property names could be lowercase. How can I modify this to still make it work?

Comment: @Prabhu : Yeah it can be dome just by using `toUpperCase()` see the update in the answer

Comment: Thanks. Only thing I had to change form pickyBy to pick. Perhaps the versions are different.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `.pick` method:

```
_.pick(myItems, _.keys(ACCEPTABLE_ITEMS))
```

> Essentially, myItems property names could be lowercase. How can I modify this to still make it work?

If you want to ignore the cases, one option is:

```
const keys = _.map(ACCEPTABLE_ITEMS, (_, key) => key.toLowerCase() );
_.pickBy(myItems, (_, key) => _.includes(keys, key.toLowerCase()) );
```

Comment: Thanks, I made a small change to my question. Essentially, myItems property names could be lowercase. How can I modify this to still make it work?